# Imgur.net nugget : Make progress bar of my upload

Tags: upload, progress-bar, xamarin.forms, imgur

I use this nugget to upload my image to imgur : http://imgurapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
And i work with Xamarin Forms in MVVM.

I want to display the progress bar of the upload of my image, but i can't found how i can do that in the documentation.

This is my code :

```
var mediaFile = await _mediaPicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions());
await UploadImage(mediaFile.Source);
```

And my function

```
public async Task UploadImage(Stream source)
{
    var client = new ImgurClient(ConstantKeys.ImgurClientId, ConstantKeys.ImgurClientSecret);
    var endpoint = new ImageEndpoint(client);

    try
    {
        var image = await endpoint.UploadImageStreamAsync(source);  

        var link = image.Link;
        ImageLink = link;
        _clipboardService.CopyToClipboard(link);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"/!\ DEBUG - UploadImage method : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would need to see some type of progress when you call UploadImageStreamAsync. Glancing at the docs, it didn't seem immediately obvious on how to do that. But I suppose you could poll the source.Position to get the general idea of how it's going.